# Why are my vassals revolting when I give them just one title?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm at holy war with some Muslim region, so I have focus all of my units there. Now there are a hell of a lot of revolts going on, one after another. I think it's because I control about 98% of the land titles. I have appointed some Barons, but that's all. If give a county title or a Duchy title to a another vassal, then after a few months, they declare war on me. The only title I can give with out taking a risk is baron title (or can they declare war on me?).

Before I grant a land title, the character's opinion of me is 100, but after I grant them any kind of title, opinion becomes -100. I don't know why that is, that's another reason why I don't grant land titles. My crown authority is high but it was like that since the beginning. And because of this I think there are thieves guilds and stuff. What can I do about this problem? I'm playing as the Kingdom of England. For wars, I'm using mercenaries.

Comment: If you hover over the opinion number, it will tell you *why* is it that way. What does the popup say? (Too many ducal titles can be one of the problems.)

Comment: Main negativity opinion is dimension is too big and too many held duchies .!

Comment: Well then, that tells you what you need to do. And if your demesne is too big, that also means you're not getting as much money out of your counties as you could.

Comment: What about the other problem I have that every time I give them land they rise up against me.

Comment: I think that's because they hate you, so you if you give up enough land at once, they won't raise up. Or at least not as quickly.

Comment: Thanks man it worked.now I get hell of lot income they're aren't any thieves guilds ether. but one problem they fight each other and I can't construct anything in the land I given to my nobles or upgrade. Help me with that too plz!!!!

Comment: @Randularipcord, those make great separate questions. Ask two new questions: one about building things in other nobles' territories, and one about them fighting each other. On Arquade, we try to keep each question specific: you ask about something specific that's your problem, and the answers help you with that specific problem. Then anyone with that specific problem will get great answers to solving that problem. Welcome to Arquade!

Answer (score 14):

### Finding out why they hate you

To find out why people don't like you, hover over the opinion number to find out why: (alas, the cursor isn't showing in this screenshot. I assure you, it's hovering over the number.)

[image: screenshot of ruler info screen, with mouse-over text from "their opinion of you" number showing the few contributions to that number: taxes, I'm a foreigner, shared personality trait, and a good state diplomacy and prestige]

You can find out why people don't like you from *any* screen that shows their opinion number. Here's another example:

[image: screenshot of diplomacy screen, showing mouse-over text from "their opinion of you" showing lots of contributions to opinion: they want counties, they love that I give them duchies, they're ambitious, we have different personalities, etc.]

### Doing something about them hating you

Vassals often rebel because they don't like you. Once you've worked out why they hate you, try to do something about it. If you have 98% of the titles in a realm, then, as you mentioned in the comments, they probably think your demesne is too large. (Fun fact: "demesne" is actually pronounced like "domain." Language is weird.)

To fix both of your problems (demesne too large, nobles hate you when you give out a title), you need to give out a *lot* of titles at the same time. Your demesne limit is in the upper-right corner of the screen; for you, it probably says something like "20/5", which means your demesne limit is 5, and you have 20 titles. The "20" will be red, and there's probably a notification at the top of the screen talking about that (unless you made it go away).

**You need to do three things:**

1. Pause the game
2. Give away all your excess titles, until you're within your demesne limit.
3. Give away some excess duchies, until you're down to 2. (You get -10 opinion against all of your vassals per duchy above 2.)

If you can, arrange it so that you have 2 duchies, and all of the counties within those 2 duchies, and you're within your demesne limit. Spread out the titles a bit, so you don't have one Super Duke who's going to challenge your power.

There's some other advice for preventing revolts [over at this other Arquade answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/109516/9522), but this will get you started.

Many thanks to @svick for figuring out the actual problem here.

(As a side note, you probably also have some note about being the "wrong holder type" for your titles.  You're a noble, you'll get the best benefit from holding castles (i.e., baron titles) and counties (count/earl titles). Give away your cities and churches to other people. (And when you hit your demesne limit, give away the baron titles and keep the count titles.))

Comment: Great answer. One thing that should be noted, is that you don't actually have to be within the demesne limit. Some times, you get more income from being a few titles above your limit, than is reduced by the tax penalty, plus you get the full levy. If you can live with the negative opinion modifiers, that might be preferable.

Comment: In recent versions of the game, your demesne levies are penalized heavily for being over the demesne limit (20% per holding, I think - it might increase non-linearly as you go higher over the limit). Any more, I only stay over my limit if I'm on the cusp of deciding who to give it to, inviting a potential claimant to vassalize and press, or waiting for a regency to end.